# Combine Two Dictionaries, Replacing values associated with duplicate keys in Pyhon?

Tags: python, dictionary

Say there are two dictionaries.

```py
dict1 = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}

dict2 = {'a':1,'b':'yellow','c':3,'e':5}
```

How would one append values in `dict2` to `dict1` while also replacing new values with equal keys.

Intended Result:
`dict1 = {'a':1,'b':'yellow','c':3,'d':4,e':5}`

Been struggling with this one for a while.

Answer (score 4):

Unpack the dictionaries in the order you want them to be superseded:

```py
dict1 = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}
dict2 = {'a':1,'b':'yellow','c':3,'e':5}
result = {**dict1,**dict2}
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4, 'f':6}
dict2 = {'a':1,'b':'yellow','c':3,'e':5}

k1 = dict1.keys()
k2 = dict2.keys()
keys_diff = list(set(k1) - set(k2))
for key in keys_diff:
  dict2[key] = dict1[key]
dict2
```

Comment: While this should work, it's doing a lot of unnecessary work creating the sets and set difference. It's enough to just overwrite all existing keys with the value in `dict2`, since writing to a dict replaces any pre-existing values.